# How do I migrate a site into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have a wordpress account and I have been using this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/

for sometime now but I want to convert that into wordpress. I know how to do basic site migration but I don't know about how to convert javascripts and more than one css files

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert anything if you have the files(js and css). Short story to move that into wordpress.
Create a new theme, use Enqueue to enque your scripts from functions.php(you can do it from header.php too, but it's not best practice and it will work slower). You can take a look at this. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script and at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development for how to create a theme and how should it look.

For home.php or index.php you'll need a simple query with a counter. The counter is for the css id(item1, item2, etc).